# Can the Friendly ORM be used alongside a traditional database schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schemaless

Can I use ActiveRecord for existing models and Friendly for new models?

Basically, I want to decide which models I'd like to be schemaless and which models I'd like to be done the "old" style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible. In the worst case you will have to assign a separate database to Friendly with Friendly.configure.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. There's no reason you can't use Friendly alongside ActiveRecord models.

As Manfred says, you could assign a separate database to Friendly - or not. Either way.